# Convert Date from JavaScript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, angular

I have this Date value in angular 6 application:

```
expires_at: Date;
```

In Java getter I use String to get the value:

```
private String expires_at;
```

But when I convert using this code:

From String to LocalDateTime

```
terminals.setExpires_at(LocalDateTime.parse(terminalDTO.getExpires_at()));
```

From LocalDateTime to String:

```
terminalNewDTO.setExpires_at(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(terminals.getExpires_at()));
```

I get this error:

```
create] due to exception [Text '2019-02-19T01:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23]
20:55:43,494 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-02-19T01:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23
20:55:43,494 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
20:55:43,494 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
20:55:43,495 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
20:55:43,495 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:477)
20:55:43,496 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.datalis.admin.backend.mapper.TerminalsMapperImpl.map(TerminalsMapperImpl.java:98)
20:55:43,496 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.TerminalController.create(TerminalController.java:104)
20:55:43,496 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
20:55:43,497 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
20:55:43,497 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
20:55:43,497 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
20:55:43,497 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

This is the date value: `2/20/19, 3:00 AM` which I try to send.

Comment: You're using "Z" for "Zulu time"/UTC?

Comment: I don't know. This is from date picker.

Comment: You could use `OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-02-19T01:00:00.000Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);`

Comment: I don’t believe you get the same stacktrace from the second code line added in your recent edit. Please quote exact stacktrace for each (or post a new question with the new issue).

Comment: OneLiner ~ `ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-02-19T01:00:00.000Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME).toLocalDateTime();`

Comment: it works if you take the date as java.util.Date type instead of string

Comment: Your example data is contradictory. The `Exception` throws says 1 AM on the 19th. But your prose says 3 AM on the 20th? Which is it? Or are you trying to adjust between some time zone and UTC? If so, what is the `Continent/Region` of your desired time zone?

Answer (score 13):

## UTC

The `Z` means an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds. In other words, [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) itself. The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu”.

Parse using `Instant` class, which represents a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-02-19T01:00:00.000Z" ) ;
```

That input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats be default for both parsing and generating strings.

```
instant.toString() // generates a ISO 8601 string.
```

## Two hours ahead of UTC

You said in the Question:

> This is the date value: 2/20/19, 3:00 AM

If the original value was 3 AM, apparently it was in a time zone two hours ahead of UTC. That could be any of several time zones, as you can see in this [list in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (that list may not be quite up-to-date, beware).

I will arbitrarily go with with `Africa/Tripoli`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tripoli" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Adjust from UTC to a time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

Both `instant` and `zdt` represent the very same moment, the same simultaneous point on the timeline. That one moment is being viewed through the wall-clock time used by the peoples of two different regions.

Imagine someone in Libya calls someone in Iceland. While chatting they both look up at the clock on their respective walls. [Iceland clocks](https://time.is/Iceland) use an offset-from-UTC of zero, while [in Libya](https://time.is/Libya) they are **two hours ahead of UTC**. So 3 AM in Libya is 1 AM in Iceland.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/6gGPyV).

> instant.toString(): 2019-02-19T01:00:00Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2019-02-19T03:00+02:00[Africa/Tripoli]

## `LocalDateTime` class is *not* for moment

> From LocalDateTime to String:

Never use `LocalDateTime` when tracking moments. A `LocalDateTime` is merely a date and a time-of-day, and nothing more. Without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, a `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment. It represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the current range of time zones around the globe.

A `LocalDateTime` is like saying “noon on the 23rd of January this year”. Do you mean noon in Tokyo Japan or Kolkata India? Or maybe Paris France? Montréal Québec? Noon in these various places happen at different moments, with hours elapsed between each.

The “Local” in `LocalDateTime` means *any* locality, or *every* locality, but does **not** mean any *particular* locality.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: @PeterPenzov I added a code example. And, FYI, this has been addressed many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search before posting, and search for more detailed discussion and more examples.

Comment: Can you show me into my code how to use your solution, please?

Comment: I suppose the quick fix would be `terminals.setExpires_at(LocalDateTime.parse(terminalDTO.getExpires_at(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));`. But please do consider if you can use `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime` in you app.

Comment: It turns out that I have one more case. Code is updated.

Comment: I think there is more to think of here. Its better to use a DatePipe in angualr ts , and convert the date to a standard format your application always expect. Use of Instant.parse() works only for the ISO_INSTANT formats (your current case).  If the format changes by any chance in your UI, the code will break in back-end. The best approach to this will be always use UTC timestamps for service data.

Comment: @PeterPenzov I do not see another “case” in your Question. My Answer shows how to parse an ISO 8601 string in UTC and adjust to some time zone. What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You also could use:

```
String expires_at = "2/20/19, 3:00 AM";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy, h:mm a"); 
Date date = parser.parse(expires_at);
```